# VBA solution for fixing "file format or file extension is not valid" error

Tags: excel, vba

Sometimes Excel file can get corrupted and start using wrong format that originally intended. In cases I have encountered usually it should be in .xlsm (Macro-enabled workbook), but recognized as .xlsx format. That returns and error message when opened preventing any modifications to it:

[image: Error message]

On the net I found several solutions suggested for fixing it: [5 Top Ways of fixing format not valid error](https://www.imyfone.com/repair-file/excel-file-format-or-extension-is-not-valid/)

However for me it not always working so I have put up short VBA code in order to try different fix using some suggestions and examples I have found. I will share the code in the comment as StackOverflow suggest - Q&A style.

Answer (score 0):

First new macro enabled workbook is required. In it - create a new Module and put code provided bellow:

```
Sub ChangeFileFormat_V1()
    
Dim strCurrentFileExt, currentExt As String
Dim strNewFileExt, newExt As String
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile
Dim xlFile As Workbook
Dim strNewName As String
Dim strFolderPath, pathInput As String
 
currentExt = InputBox("Please enter current file extension:" & vbNewLine & "for e.g. - .xlsx", "Please enter current file extension")

strCurrentFileExt = currentExt

newExt = InputBox("Please enter desired file extension:" & vbNewLine & "for e.g. - .xlsm", "Please enter desired file extension")

strNewFileExt = newExt

If StrPtr(newExt) = 0 Or StrPtr(currentExt) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "File extensions are required", vbCritical, "No file extensions entered!"
    Exit Sub
End If

pathInput = InputBox("Please enter destination folder path. It should look like this:" & vbNewLine & "C:\Users\rusage1\OneDrive - Novartis Pharma AG\Desktop\Ruxolitinib PV\Test", "Please enter path")
'path should be set here
strFolderPath = pathInput

If StrPtr(pathInput) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No path entered", vbCritical, "No path found!"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Right(strFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then

    strFolderPath = strFolderPath & "\"

End If

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.getfolder(strFolderPath)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

    strNewName = objFile.Name

    If Right(strNewName, Len(strCurrentFileExt)) = strCurrentFileExt Then
    
        strNewName = Replace(strNewName, strCurrentFileExt, strNewFileExt)
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        
        objFile.Name = strNewName
        
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End If

Next objFile

 

ClearMemory:

strCurrentFileExt = vbNullString

strNewFileExt = vbNullString

Set objFSO = Nothing

Set objFolder = Nothing

Set objFile = Nothing

Set xlFile = Nothing

strNewName = vbNullString

strFolderPath = vbNullString


MsgBox "Done! Hope this helps to open the file", vbInformation, "Done!"

End Sub
```

You can launch this macro from Developer>Macros tab or you can create a button (shape) and assign the macro to it.
Just follow the message box instructions and it should (probably work).

Before launching it few other preparation steps suggested:

- Keep file which is being fixed separated from other Excels in order
  not to break them. Create a tempolary folder! Because command is not
  picky and "fix" all the files meeting set parameters!
- Carefully follow instruction and use command at your own risk. Always make backup-copies before using.
- It is recommended to rename file before fix, since sometimes file name is also intervening with the process.

I cannot guarantee that it will work (sometimes it works not from the first try), but it is worth a shot if the file is important.